# How do I add a hook to inferior python?

Tags: init-file, python

I am sitting on OS X and I have written the following elisp to set comint-previous-input function to s-up, but my configuration is not working. What might be wrong here?

```
(add-hook 'inferior-python-mode-hook
      (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "s-<up>") 'comint-previous-input)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(kbd "s-<up>")` isn't valid.

The great thing about `kbd` is that Emacs will *tell you* the argument to pass it, if you ask it using <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>. You never have to guess.

In this case, Emacs tells me that `"<s-up>"` is the correct argument.